# How do named function expressions work?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've found the example in the book and it was called «named function expression». Although authors say, that it's not common thing to see, but it's interesting to me to figure out the mechanics of it.

Declaring the function:

```
> function NF() { return true; };
undefined
> NF();
true
```

Assigning:

```
> let variable = NF();
> variable; // no parentheses, it's ok.
true
```

Named function expression (function expression + declaration):

```
> let variable2 = function NF2() { return true; };
undefined
> variable2;
[Function: NF2] // need to add parentheses to get true
```

So:

```
> variable2();
true
> let variable3 = function NF3() { return true; }();
undefined
> variable3;
true // now we get true too, without any parentheses;
```

The question is: why? Why do we need the additional parentheses in the case number two? It seems inconsistent to me.

And one more thing: calling NF2() (and NF3 too) returns ReferenceError.

```
> typeof NF2;
'undefined'
> variable2;
[Function: NF2]
```

Tested in Node.JS REPL v8. Also want to know, if the behavior the same in browsers. Thanks.

UPD: I've got the answer from @RobG that names of declared functions are stored in their local scope, but running some tests haven't made things clearer:

```
> let inner, outer;
undefined
> outer = function inner()
... {
... console.log(`referred`);
... inner = () => true
... };
[Function: inner]
> typeof inner;
'undefined'
> typeof outer;
'function'
> outer();
referred
undefined
> typeof inner;
'undefined'
```

Why inner is still undefined? It was declared globally. The result of the executing outer() the second time is still that same, not «true», so it wasn't overwritten.

Comment: *the additional parentheses* make an IIFE - an immediately invoked function expression ... `let variable3 = function NF3() { return true; }();` is basically shorthand for `let temp = function NF3() { return true; }; let variable3 = temp();`

Comment: The name of a named function expression is only available within the function (except for old buggy versions of IE), so in `var x = function foo(){};`, then outside the function *foo* is undefined.

Comment: You seems to be confused about function *definitions* and function *calls*. *"Why do we need the additional parentheses in the case number two?"* There are **no** additional parenthesis. In every example you are using the same number of parenthesis. (1) `NF();` (2) `variable2();` (3) `function NF3() { return true; }()`

Comment: @RobG Correct me if I'm wrong, but somehow I recall that exceptions within a named function always show the function name in the error console, which encourages naming them even if they are assigned to a variable or immediately invoked

Comment: @Brandon: Using named function expression can make debugging easier (although function names have changed a bit in ES6 so it really doesn't matter as much anymore). But that has nothing to do with what Rob was talking about.

Comment: @BrandonArnold—debuggers (and development environments in general) can do a lot of things outside the language specification, you shouldn't interpret their behaviour or features as necessarily being part of the language. Try programming in a text editor with *alert* as your only debugging tool—welcome to scripting before the console and debuggers!

Comment: @RobG ≈ so, can you say using named function expressions is a good practice? if the names of these functions are local scoped, they don't produce any garbage in the global scope and may be useful while debugging process. also I wonder if there such thing in other languages like C++ or Python? Probably, it's a useful practice across all the languages, even though I expect that JavaScript is something that stands aside most of the time with its quirky non-classic programming logic.

Comment: @RobG ≈ I've updated the question.

Comment: @JulyMorning—they were considered "bad practice" because of an [*IE (JScript) bug*](https://kangax.github.io/nfe/#jscript-bugs) that made them global. But other than that, I can't see any issues with them.

Comment: @RobG one last question. Does the bug still persist let's say in Edge? I thought IE is dead already.

Comment: @JulyMorning—there are a huge number of web hosts running on all sorts of devices, you shouldn't just concentrate on just the most popular desktop browsers.It would take you a few moments to test - put `!function foo(){}; typeof foo` in the console (it seems to have been fixed in 1E 9).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that code works in the same way in browsers, so let's explain a little your code.

Declaring the function

```
function NF() { return true }
// call NF() function will output
// true
```

Assigning function's value to variable

```
let _variable = NF();
// the code above, will execute FN function and then store it into variable _variable
```

Named function expression (function expression + declaration):

```
let _variable2 = function FN2() { return true; };
// The code above will create FN2 function and then assign it to the variable called _variable2.
// note that the function only will assign it to the _variable2 but no its results because is not executed yet
// this _variable2() will call FN2 function that was assigned to the _variable2
```

finally this code

```
let variable3 = function NF3() { return true; }();
// call variable3 will output true.
// Why calling variable3 output the returning value from NF3 function ?
// that is because you are declaring and in the same way executing the NF3 function and then assign it to the variable3
```

So why calling `typeof NF2` is `undefined` ? , that is because NF2 function it's only available into the variable3's scope, the function called NF2 is not declared into the top level, I mean into the window scope for browser for example, so that FN2 function only lives into the variable that contains the function itself.

I hope it can help you.

Comment: *"Assigning function to variable"* This is wrong, the comment inside the example is correct. The *return value* of the function call is assigned to the variable.

Comment: @FelixKling you are right, I just copy the code from the question, sorry I will fix it

Comment: Ah I didn't realize you just copied the "titles" from the question.

Answer (score 1):

The parentheses in case 2 are a way of calling the function immediately after defining it. This is known as an Immediately Invoked Function Expression or IIFE. Usually it is required to surround the function definition in parentheses, viz:

```
(
    function doIt() {
        console.log('Do it.');
    }
)()  // "Do it."
```

But not in this case, since you are setting the results to a variable. The following are equivalent:

```
// example 1
let nf3 = function NF3() { return true; };
let variable2 = nf3(); // true

// example 2, same result
let variable3 = function NF3() { return true; }(); // true
```

Notice that without the parentheses at the end, (see `nf3` in example 1 above), you are setting the variable `nf3` to the function `NF3()`. Whereas with the parentheses as in `variable3` above, you are setting the variable to the results of the function call, and not the function itself.

Answer (score 0):

To explain the differences in clearer way lets use `timestamps`

```
let now = function () { return + new Date(); };

// now() => 1506483778066
// ...
// now() => 1506483779723
```

Here `now` is a function that returns the current `timestamp`. We need to call it as `now()` and with every invocation the function body is executed.

```
let timeAgo = function () { return + new Date(); }();

// timeAgo => 1506483798754
// ...
// ...
// timeAgo => 1506483798754
```

Here `timeAgo` is an assigned variable that stores the timestamp at which the function was executed. Value of `timeAgo` never changes in this case.